# JQuery: Calculation plugin doesn't calculate to total prices

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

**:plugin**
Homepage: [Link](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/calculation/calculation.plugin.htm).

**:javascript**

```
  $("[id^=total_price_ht]").calc(
    // the equation to use for the calculation
    "qty * price",
    {
      qty: $("[id^=unit_quantity_]"),
      price: $("[id^=unit_price_ht_]")
    },
    function (s){
      // return the number as a dollar amount
      return "$" + s.toFixed(2);
    }
  );
```

**:html**

```
<tr id="lines[0]">
  <td>
    <input id="0" type="checkbox" class="hiddenCheckbox">
    <label for="0" class="prettyCheckbox checkbox list"><span class="holderWrap" style="width: 18px; height: 19px; "><span class="holder" style="width: 18px; "></span></span></label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="required" name="lines[0][title]" placeholder="Title" type="text">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input name="lines[0][description]" placeholder="Description" type="text">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="required" id="unit_quantity_0" name="lines[0][quantity]" placeholder="Quantité" type="text" value="0,00">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="required" id="unit_price_ht_0" name="lines[0][unit_price_ht]" placeholder="Prix unit. HT" type="text" value="0,00">
  </td>
  <td class="price" id="total_price_ht_0">$0.00</td>
</tr>
```

Once the page loads, I can see '$0.00" in the total_price_ht field but it's value doesn't get changed when I change the quantity or the price.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the generated HTML?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker I posted the generated HTML. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks--Is this the plugin you're using? http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/calculation/calculation.plugin.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to call the `calc` plugin every time you want to recalculate the total:

```
$("[id^='unit_quantity_'], [id^='unit_price_ht_']").keyup(recalc);


function recalc() {

    $("[id^='total_price_ht']").calc(
    // the equation to use for the calculation
    "qty * price", {
        bind: "keyup",
        qty: $("[id^='unit_quantity_']"),
        price: $("[id^='unit_price_ht_']")
    }, function(s) {
        // return the number as a dollar amount
        return "$" + s.toFixed(2);
    });
}

recalc();
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/upEZW/